# For loop to create multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, google-fusion-tables

I am displaying data from a Google Fusion Table on my website. So far I am able to display the data as `p` tags.

```
<p>Hotel Name</p>
<p>www.hotelwebsite.com</p>
<p>Hotel description</p>
<p>http://www.hotelwebsite.com/hotelimage.jpg</p>
```

But I would like to change the element types for each item.

```
<h2>Hotel Name</h2>
<a href="http://www.hotelwebsite.com">www.hotelwebsite.com</a>
<p>Hotel description</p>
<img src="http://www.hotelwebsite.com/hotelimage.jpg"/>
```

Is it possible to keep the for loop, but create different elements that I can style differently?

```
htmlTable.appendChild(tableRow);
for (var i = 0; i < resp.rows.length; i++) {
  var tableRow = document.createElement('div');

  for (var j = 0; j < resp.rows[i].length; j++) {
    var tableData = document.createElement('p');
    var content = document.createTextNode(resp.rows[i][j]);
    tableData.appendChild(content);
    tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
  }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alsjohnstone/LqmgcLa6/8/

Comment: Perhaps it would make for much simpler and readable code to unwind the loop completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row has 4 columns (name, website url, description, image url), rather than incrementing through each cell, increment through each row, applying the columns as required.

```
for (var i = 0; i < resp.columns.length; i++) {        
    var tableHeader = document.createElement('p');
    tableRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
    htmlTable.appendChild(tableRow);
    var tableRow = document.createElement('div');

    var tableData = document.createElement('h2');
    var content = document.createTextNode(resp.rows[i][0]); // hotel name
    tableData.appendChild(content);
    tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
    var tableData = document.createElement('a');
    tableData.setAttribute('src',resp.rows[i][1]); // website
    tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
    var tableHeader = document.createElement('p');
    tableRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
    var content = document.createTextNode(resp.rows[i][2]); // hotel description
    tableData.appendChild(content);
    tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
    var tableData = document.createElement('img');
    tableData.setAttribute('src',resp.rows[i][3]); // website
    tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
    htmlTable.appendChild(tableRow);
}
result.appendChild(htmlTable);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5e201mse/7/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function dataHandler(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var htmlTable = document.createElement('div');
    
    var tableRow = document.createElement('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.columns.length; i++) {        
        var tableHeader = document.createElement('p');
        tableRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
        htmlTable.appendChild(tableRow);
        var tableRow = document.createElement('div');

        var tableData = document.createElement('h2');
        var content = document.createTextNode(resp.rows[i][0]); // hotel name
        tableData.appendChild(content);
        tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
        var tableData = document.createElement('a');
        tableData.setAttribute('src',resp.rows[i][1]); // website
        tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
        var tableHeader = document.createElement('p');
        tableRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
        var content = document.createTextNode(resp.rows[i][2]); // hotel description
        tableData.appendChild(content);
        tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
        var tableData = document.createElement('img');
        tableData.setAttribute('src',resp.rows[i][3]); // website
        tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
        htmlTable.appendChild(tableRow);
    }
    result.appendChild(htmlTable);
}

function getData() {
    
    // Builds a Fusion Tables SQL query and hands the result to  dataHandler
    var queryUrlHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=';
    var queryUrlTail = '&key=AIzaSyCMILeBTrsiwVnO9_SSJ4HYtzZl14dXdRA';
    var tableId = '1_wBUixHJqO_W95zMHk_eP8wQKBuXvHEfvNgfTBSC';

    // write your SQL as normal, then encode it
    var query = "SELECT 'Name', 'URL', 'Description', 'Image' FROM " + tableId + " ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(Postcode, LATLNG(50.879311, 0.063803)) LIMIT 100; "
    var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);

    var jqxhr = $.get(queryurl, dataHandler, "jsonp");
}

getData();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable at the inner loop and check its value and create different element for different values and if the variable reach '3' create the element and set its value to '0'

Answer (score 0):

Using ternary and the modulus operator, you can make every other element a header.

```
   for (var j = 0; j < resp.rows[i].length; j++) {
        var ele = j % 2 !== 0 ? "p" : "h1";
        var tableData = document.createElement(ele);
        alert(resp.rows[i][j]);

        var content = document.createTextNode(resp.rows[i][j]);
        tableData.appendChild(content);
        tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LqmgcLa6/9/

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work a treat. Do you know how I could get the image URL as an image tag? and is it possible to add it in the same for loop?

Comment: Well, since I already answered your original question, I would be happy to demo that for you if you hit the checkmark by my answer :)